# Changing the background colors of two divs with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm not sure how to explain what I'm lookin for so I'm going to put it in steps.

1. Two divs have different colors lets say one is red the other is blue.
2. When i click on the red div i want the background color of the red div to turn orange.
3. When i click on the blue div i want the red div to turn back to red and make the blue div turn orange.

I have a code i have been trying to twist it to make it how i want it to be but i can't seem to figure out how to. If you could help me that would be very kind of you. Thank you for all information you can give me.

The code will be used for a menu, if you could also put it as if it were to be more than just two divs.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").on({
        mouseenter: function(){
            $(this).css("background-color", "green");
        },  
        mouseleave: function(){
            $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        },
        click: function(){
            $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        }  
    });
});
```

```css
div { background-color: pink;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div style="width: 80px; padding: 25px;">Example 1</div>
<div style="width: 80px; padding: 25px;">Example 2</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can never click on a red div, because `mouseenter` changes its color before you click.

Comment: I suggest you use classes rather than `.css()`. Then you can check whether the DIV you clicked on has a particular class, and use `addClass` and `removeClass` to change the classes.

Comment: Nb. Using javascript to set colours on hover state like this will overwrite anything you have set on click events. Not sure if this is what you are after - if not you're better using css hover pseudo selectors.

Comment: You can use `$("div").not(this)` to refer to the other DIVs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you asked for but i guess you couldn't explain completely what you want. I made this version based on your steps and also made another one based on a guess that maybe that's the one which you looking for.

**Version 1** (based on your steps):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.red").on('click', function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('is-orange')) $(this).addClass('is-orange');
    });

    $("div.blue").on('click', function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('is-orange')) $(this).addClass('is-orange');
        if($(this).siblings('.red').hasClass('is-orange')) $(this).siblings('.red').removeClass('is-orange')
    });
});
```

```css
.red {background-color: red;}
.blue {background-color: blue;}
.is-orange {background-color: orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="red" style="width: 80px; padding: 25px;">Example 1</div>
<div class="blue" style="width: 80px; padding: 25px;">Example 2</div>
```

**Version 2** (more complete):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.red").on('click', function(){
     if(!$(this).hasClass('is-orange')) $(this).addClass('is-orange');
     else $(this).removeClass('is-orange');
     if($(this).siblings('.blue').hasClass('is-orange')) $(this).siblings('.blue').removeClass('is-orange');
    });
    $("div.blue").on('click', function(){
     if(!$(this).hasClass('is-orange')) $(this).addClass('is-orange');
     else $(this).removeClass('is-orange');
     if($(this).siblings('.red').hasClass('is-orange')) $(this).siblings('.red').removeClass('is-orange');
    });
});
```

```css
.red {background-color: red;}
.blue {background-color: blue;}
.is-orange {background-color: orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red" style="width: 80px; padding: 25px;">Example 1</div>
<div class="blue" style="width: 80px; padding: 25px;">Example 2</div>
```

**P.S**: i helped "classes" to make this work, if you need this code be without classes, just asked, i will edit this codes.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just want an `active` class on the div's.  Something like this;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").on({
    click: function() {
      $("div.active").removeClass("active"); //turn off active for the other divs
      $(this).addClass("active");  //make this one active
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.active {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <div style="width: 80px; padding: 25px;">Example 1</div>
  <div style="width: 80px; padding: 25px;">Example 2</div>
  <div style="width: 80px; padding: 25px;">Example 3</div>

</body>

</html>
```

In this case you just need to add more `divs` to the html, I've added a third.

Answer (score -1):

Add an class in your stylesheet i.e.

```
.active{
  background-color: orange;
}
```

and with jQuery just toggle the class, like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").on('click', function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```